# Como faço para que um script funcione num navegador específico?

Tags: javascript, html, script, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet

Como faço para que um script funcione apenas num navegador específico, por exemplo: que funcione apenas no Chrome? E o contrário: bloquear que o script funcione num navegador específico? O que eu tenho que acrescentar ao código? Eu uso HTML e o script em questão é:

```
function openWindow() {          
  window.open("banner","Teste","width=731,height=420,top=100,left=250");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a propriedade `navigator`, acessível através do objeto global `window`.

Essa propriedade contém diversas informações relativas ao navegador do usuário. Para essa resposta, iremos focar na propriedade `userAgent`, que contém uma `string` um pouco complicada e cheia de informações. Entre elas, podemos achar o nome do navegador em uso. Algo assim:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/536 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.111 Safari/536.47

---

Com o exemplo abaixo, você pode detectar qual navegador o usuário está usando:

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome')) {
  alert('Você usa o Google Chrome')
} else if (navigator.userAgent.includes('Opera')) {
  alert('Você usa o Opera')
} else if (navigator.userAgent.includes('Firefox')) {
  alert('Você usa o Mozilla Firefox')
} else if (navigator.userAgent.includes('Safari')) {
  alert('Você usa o Safari')
} else if (navigator.userAgent.includes('MSIE')) {
  alert('Você ainda usa IE? Como consegue?!')
} else {
  alert('Você usa um navegador pouco comum...')
}
```